# Upgrade instance type, can not connect anymore

Tags: amazon-ec2, upgrade

I had a micro instance and I would do the upgarde for a small instance. What I did was stop my instance, right button> type instance> set to small. Done it can not access my instance, neither the browser nor via ssh. Can someone help me? I lost all my files from disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any useful details about your setup, about how you connect, etc..

But having been in a sort of similar situation before, I'll suggest checking your elastic IP if you have one. If you do, the elastic IP was disassociated when you stopped the instance. Attach it again.